# emacs-pgtk for WSL2 - identification and clipboard issues

Tags: clipboard, gccemacs, pgtk

I installed emacs-pgtk version 29.0.50 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.33, cairo version 1.16.0) from the git repo following [these](https://batsov.com/articles/2021/12/19/building-emacs-from-source-with-pgtk/) instructions with

```
./configure --with-native-compilation --with-xml2 --with-json --with-pgtk
```

Shortcut on Windows Start menu did not appear so I manually created using [this](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/45#issuecomment-1250093137) suggestion (essentially creating a shortcut to the location, `C:\Windows\System32\wslg.exe ~ -d Ubuntu-22.04 emacs`).

Overall it looks to be working okay but some strange things.

1. Clipboard: I am unable to paste content into Windows applications after using `kill-ring-save` and `kill-region` in this emacs-pgtk that I launch with the shortcut. However, `kill-line` works as expected and I can paste content into Windows; and `kill-ring-save` and `kill-region` work if I launch emacs-pgtk from the WSL2 Ubuntu terminal. Why would this behavior be different?
2. Is there a way to identify that this is a Linux GUI app in emacs? I already have font specifications for emacs-pgtk opened from the WSL2 Ubuntu terminal, but the I need to specify a different font size for the Linux GUI app. The `system-type` (`gnu/linux`) is same as if I launch from the terminal so I cannot use that to distinguish the GUI app.